# Broken pipe error message

Tags: pipe, 14.10

When I boot up in Ubuntu 14.10 beta 2, I get the following message for a moment on the screen:

```
error while reading descriptor: broken pipe:
```

The screen then goes black for a moment and then continues on to the login screen.

Can anyone advise me as to what this message indicates and what I need to do about it?

Comment: Do you have any additional context?... This is happening to me after installing nvidia-340 driver

Comment: Additionally it was confirmed as a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/init-system-helpers/+bug/1364630

Comment: In my case, unfortunately, I don't get the normal logon screen, only a virtual terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like its a bug, so you might want to have a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1364630

Comment: The bug is mistitled.  It includes not just Nvidia graphics, but  also occurs in some circumstances (like mine) with Intel graphics.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The following is my screen.

```
There are screens on:
    75854.lot       (08/24/2019 04:11:14 AM)        (Detached)
```

When I tried reattaching by using `screen -r lot`, it threw `broken pipe:` error. 
Therefore I tried,

```
screen -r 75854
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this could be due to varied reasons:

1. some i/o issue.
2. The write buffer of the pipe is full.
3. Writing failed because there are no processes which could read from the pipe.

Also, it seems they had a bug earlier and re-installing the OS should fix the issue.

[launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/init-system-helpers/+bug/1364630)

Comment: Reinstalling is a last resort because it means that you have to recreate your entire operating environment.  I've been hunting for a week for an answer that doesn't require me to do that.